# Magento 2: Keep use default value when Updating product attribute programmatically in store view level

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, eav

I have a dropdown product attribute in store view level that i need to update programmatically for specific store:

I tried to update the product attribute programmatically like this:

```
// \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $_productAction
$storeId = 3;
$productId = 35;
$this->productAction->updateAttributes(array(
            $productId
        ) , array('test_id'=>30), $storeId);
```

The product attribute value is updated successfully.

The problem is when i checked the product attribute value to use default value like below:

[image]

it will be unchecked if I run those code, even though i set the product attribute value same as the default value

[image]

How can i avoid or prevent this and keep value checked, even if i update the value same as the default product attribute value ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior as you are passing the `$storeId=3` so it will save your value on store-level no matter value is the same as the default value.
If you don't want that then pass `$storeId=0`.

Hope this information will help you.